# Installing of Microsoft ACME web camera

Tags: 11.10, webcam

How to install ACME web camera from Microsoft type installation disc on UBUNTU11.10? I used WINE to do it but without success. It shows error 1627!

Answer (score 1):

If you meant an ACME brand webcam, just plug it in. You don't need to install the windows drivers through wine. You can test it out by installing cheese from the software center.

Comment: Hey, Scott, I have CHEESE & I tried to start my webcamera with it but: 1. CHEESE doesn´t start without installed any camera be4

Comment: Hey, Scott, I have CHEESE & I tried to start my webcamera with it but: 1. CHEESE doesn´t start without installed any camera be4 & 2. WINE reports an error 1627, after its renewing - 1628